# Small letters at autocomplete in Fortran Code Nav

Tags: ide, fortran

How can you change the settings of the autocompletes in Fortran Code Nav so that it is completed with the small letters?

Comment: Don't ask what people use. That is irrelevant.

Comment: contact the author? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TiemenSchreuder.FortranCodeNav

Comment: Yes, I could only find the e-mail from one of the two developers. But until now no answer arrived.